# Once i renamed the component in angular, im unable to run the ng serve cammand. What would the cause be?

Tags: angular

```
./src/app/components/item/item.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected identifier.
  ╷
3 │ . e-item{
  │  ^
  ╵
  src\app\components\item\item.component.scss 3:2  root stylesheet



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh8p1.png)

I have been continously trying to solve yet im unable to to find the solution, how could this be solved?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space between the dot and the CSS class in line 3. Remove the space so it would look like so:

```scss
.e-item {
```

Comment: oh! indeeed the error went away......